# changing regular html button to asp.net button control

Tags: asp.net

I have to keep the formatting the exact same way that I got this static html page but have to add some code to it.  Right now, I'm stuck with a regular html submit button and I need to figure out a way to switch it to an asp.net button without ruining the format.

So how do I convert:

```
<button type="submit"><span><span>Review</span></span></button>"
```

To a regular ASP.NET control while keeping the span tags? The button I was hoping had some innerhtml property but it doesn't.

Comment: Post the markup for the current button

Comment: Think you lost some of your tags :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply place the following attributes in the button :

```
runat="server" id="btnSubmit" onserverclick="DoSomething"
```

and wire it up to the code-behind

```
protected void DoSomething(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Write("Hello world");
}
```

and it's turned into a server control.

Answer (score 0):

Erm, I trust you are not using inline style attributes.

if thats the case then simply substitute the class atteribute with className.

if you are using inline styles then put them into a style tag and use that style name in the className attribute of the asp.net control.

is this helpful or am i missing something?

Comment: I made a mistake posting, didn't properly insert my html